# Click LinearLayout to execute action

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-xml

I have a layout that's used in *several* activities. I have a `LinearLayout` in the layout that looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/like_button"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/like_button_iv"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_like"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="100"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I need to make it so that if a user clicks this `LinearLayout`, it executes an action and then changes the `ImageView` `src` to a different icon.

Also, is using a `LinearLayout` in this situation ideal?

How can I do this?

Comment: You don't need that LinearLayout at all. And so the ImageView. Just use a **compound drawable** in your TextView and make the TextView clickable. This will help flattening your layouts for better performances. Simply transfer the mean properties from the LinearLayout to the TextView.

Comment: Thanks, that answers one question. Any ideas on the other?

Comment: Use `setCompoundDrawablesWithintrinsicBounds()` to change the drawable programmatically. Note - It can be ANY valid Drawable, not necessarily a png file.

Comment: add to the Xml in LinearLayout android:clickable="true"

Comment: The second question was how do I get the button to execute an action? How do I implement the click event?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your ImageView to be clickable and make it to do the job.
In your activity class declare a ImageView.

```
ImageView myimage;
```

In your `oncreate` method add

```
myimage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.like_button_iv);    
myimage.setOnclickListener(this);
```

In method `onClick` add:

```
myimage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.differntsrc));
```

Use your logic for selecting image source `differntsrc`